# ¿Por qué no se visualiza en chrome mi slider hecho con html, css y js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, chrome

Encontré un video tutorial para poder realizar mi slider usando html, css y JavaScript. El problema es que a la hora de visualizarlo en el chrome no me aparece nada. Creo que está en los JQuerys algo, porque se supone que debo agregar a la carpeta del css un archivo llamado lightslider.css y en la carpeta js otro archivo llamado lightslider.js

Luego viene el index.html

```html
<!--doctype html-->
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce Slider</title>
    <!--page-icon------------>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png">
    <!--stylesheet------------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!--light-slider.css------------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightslider.css">
    <!--Jquery-------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquerys.js"></script>
    <!--lightslider.js--------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightslider.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <section class="slider">
    <ul id="autoWidth" class="cs-hidden">
    <!--1------------------------------------>  
  <li class="item-a">
<!--box-slider--------------->
    <div class="box">
    <!--img-box---------->
    <div class="slide-img">
    <img alt="1" src="images/1.jpg">
    <!--overlayer---------->
    <div class="overlay">
    <!--buy-btn------>  
    <a href="#" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--detail-box--------->
    <div class="detail-box">
    <!--type-------->
    <div class="type">
    <a href="#">Rabbed Cardigan</a>
    <span>Noe Arrival</span>
    </div>
    <!--price-------->
    <a href="#" class="price">$23</a>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>      
</li>
    <!--2------------------------------------>  
  <li class="item-b">
<!--box-slider--------------->
    <div class="box">
    <!--img-box---------->
    <div class="slide-img">
    <img alt="2" src="images/2.jpg">
    <!--overlayer---------->
    <div class="overlay">
    <!--buy-btn------>  
    <a href="#" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--detail-box--------->
    <div class="detail-box">
    <!--type-------->
    <div class="type">
    <a href="#">Rabbed Cardigan</a>
    <span>Noe Arrival</span>
    </div>
    <!--price-------->
    <a href="#" class="price">$20</a>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>      
</li>
    <!--3------------------------------------>  
  <li class="item-c">
<!--box-slider--------------->
    <div class="box">
    <!--img-box---------->
    <div class="slide-img">
    <img alt="3" src="images/3.jpg">
    <!--overlayer---------->
    <div class="overlay">
    <!--buy-btn------>  
    <a href="#" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--detail-box--------->
    <div class="detail-box">
    <!--type-------->
    <div class="type">
    <a href="#">Rabbed Cardigan</a>
    <span>Noe Arrival</span>
    </div>
    <!--price-------->
    <a href="#" class="price">$26</a>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>      
</li>
    <!--4------------------------------------>  
  <li class="item-d">
<!--box-slider--------------->
    <div class="box">
    <!--img-box---------->
    <div class="slide-img">
    <img alt="4" src="images/4.jpg">
    <!--overlayer---------->
    <div class="overlay">
    <!--buy-btn------>  
    <a href="#" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--detail-box--------->
    <div class="detail-box">
    <!--type-------->
    <div class="type">
    <a href="#">Rabbed Cardigan</a>
    <span>Noe Arrival</span>
    </div>
    <!--price-------->
    <a href="#" class="price">$27</a>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>      
</li>
    <!--5------------------------------------>  
  <li class="item-e">
<!--box-slider--------------->
```

Luego está el script.js

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autoWidth').lightSlider({
        autoWidth:true,
        loop:true,
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#autoWidth').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        } 
    });  
  });

"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": ["JSHint"],
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
},
```

Ahora, estos son los otros archivos que me están dando problemas

1. El lightslider.css

```css
/*! lightslider - v1.1.3 - 2015-04-14
* https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider
* Copyright (c) 2015 Sachin N; Licensed MIT */
/** /!!! core css Should not edit !!!/**/ 

.lSSlideOuter {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.lightSlider:before, .lightSlider:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.lightSlider {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
.lSSlideWrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.lSSlideWrapper > .lightSlider:after {
    clear: both;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSSlide {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform,height;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform,height;
    transition-property: transform,height;
    -webkit-transition-duration: inherit !important;
    transition-duration: inherit !important;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
    transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade {
    position: relative;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade > * {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade > * {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: inherit !important;
    transition-duration: inherit !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
    transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade > *.active {
    z-index: 10;
}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade > *.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
/** /!!! End of core css Should not edit !!!/**/

/* Pager */
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li a {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li:hover a, .lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li.active a {
    background-color: #428bca;
}
.lSSlideOuter .media {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.lSSlideOuter .media.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* End of pager */

/** Gallery */
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.12s linear 0s 0.35s linear 0s;
    transition: border-radius 0.12s linear 0s 0.35s linear 0s;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li.active, .lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:before, .lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:after {
    clear: both;
}
/* End of Gallery*/

/* slider actions */
.lSAction > a {
    width: 32px;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url('../img/controls.png');
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: -16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
}
.lSAction > a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.lSAction > .lSPrev {
    background-position: 0 0;
    left: 10px;
}
.lSAction > .lSNext {
    background-position: -32px 0;
    right: 10px;
}
.lSAction > a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.cS-hidden {
    height: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. Y este es el lightslider.js

```js
(function ($, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var defaults = {
        item: 3,
        autoWidth: false,
        slideMove: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        addClass: '',
        mode: 'slide',
        useCSS: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',//
        speed: 400, //ms'
        auto: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        loop: false,
        slideEndAnimation: true,
        pause: 2000,
        keyPress: false,
        controls: true,
        prevHtml: '',
        nextHtml: '',
        rtl: false,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        vertical: false,
        verticalHeight: 500,
        vThumbWidth: 100,
        thumbItem: 10,
        pager: true,
        gallery: false,
        galleryMargin: 5,
        thumbMargin: 5,
        currentPagerPosition: 'middle',
        enableTouch: true,
        enableDrag: true,
        freeMove: true,
        swipeThreshold: 40,
        responsive: [],
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        onBeforeStart: function ($el) {},
        onSliderLoad: function ($el) {},
        onBeforeSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onAfterSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforeNextSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforePrevSlide: function ($el, scene) {}
        /* jshint ignore:end */
    };
    $.fn.lightSlider = function (options) {
        if (this.length === 0) {
            return this;
        }

        if (this.length > 1) {
            this.each(function () {
                $(this).lightSlider(options);
            });
            return this;
        }

        var plugin = {},
            settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options),
            settingsTemp = {},
            $el = this;
        plugin.$el = this;

        if (settings.mode === 'fade') {
            settings.vertical = false;
        }
        var $children = $el.children(),
            windowW = $(window).width(),
            breakpoint = null,
            resposiveObj = null,
            length = 0,
            w = 0,
            on = false,
            elSize = 0,
            $slide = '',
            scene = 0,
            property = (settings.vertical === true) ? 'height' : 'width',
            gutter = (settings.vertical === true) ? 'margin-bottom' : 'margin-right',
            slideValue = 0,
            pagerWidth = 0,
            slideWidth = 0,
            thumbWidth = 0,
            interval = null,
            isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
        var refresh = {};

        refresh.chbreakpoint = function () {
            windowW = $(window).width();
            if (settings.responsive.length) {
                var item;
                if (settings.autoWidth === false) {
                    item = settings.item;
                }
                if (windowW < settings.responsive[0].breakpoint) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < settings.responsive.length; i++) {
                        if (windowW < settings.responsive[i].breakpoint) {
                            breakpoint = settings.responsive[i].breakpoint;
                            resposiveObj = settings.responsive[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Estoy usando la ultima version de brackets para editarlo.